# horizontal slider menu's sub menus display behind embedded Youtube videos

Tags: language-agnostic

I downloaded smoothmenu from dynamic drive. I am using the vertical menu with slide out sub-menus. Everything works beautifully except my page that has embedded youtube videos. On this page, the sub-menus appear behind the video. I have the site up on:
http://hardcorehockey.com.previewdns.com/videos.html

I tried to use z-index but that didn't fix it.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your embed code:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
```

If that doesn't do it, try "opaque" instead of "transparent"